# Яндекс и редирект на сайтах

Tags: веб-программирование, редирект, яндекс-поиск

Имеется несколько разных сайтов одного товара, суть в том, что если пользователь уже был на одном из сайтов раньше, то при отправке заявки ему будет скидка. В общих чертах это реализовано следующим образом:

1) пользователь заходит на сайт.

2) если у него не установлена сессия, то происходит редирект на другой, общий для всех сайт (все сайты с товарами редиректятся на него).

3) на общем сайте в файл записываются данные о посещении пользователем сайта.

4) происходит редирект обратно с общего сайта на частный.

Проблема в том, что Яндекс.Вебмастер не видит robots.txt, sitemap на этих частных сайтах, все их страницы проиндексированы с кодом 301Moved Permanently. Можно ли как-то настроить яндекс таким образом, чтобы он отдавал код 200? (без редиректа с частных сайтов на один общий реализовать скидку не получится). Как в общем это повлияет на выдачу сайтов в поиске?

Comment: Настройте правильно свой веб-сервер. У вас nginx/apache? С помощью чего настроен такой редирект?

Comment: редирект сделан с помощью обычной функции php header()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перенаправлять сайты при помощи javascript

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Яндекс не обрабатывает javascript соответсвенно все будет хорошо. Но санкции все равно можно схватить.
Может для Вас будет более хороший способ подгружать при помощи javascript на частном сайте скрипт с общего и устанавливать сессию(так например работает яндекс метрика и куча счетчиков)